# Materialize CSS slider isn't responsive?

Tags: css, materialize

I'm doing this site: [neongirslband.ru](http://neongirlsband.ru/), the first row is actually a slider. It works well for 1920px, however the photos gets cropped if the resolution is lower (phones and tablets for example). How to make it so the photo gets resized according to the current resolution? Am I'm doing something wrong here?

The site is hosted on github: https://github.com/AlexKotik/NeonSite

```
...
<div class="row" id="Photo">            
       <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li><img src="img/1.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="img/2.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="img/3.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slider').slider({ 
            fullWidth: true,
            interval: 5000,
            height: 800                
        });
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: You can view this codepen demo of Slider and carousel both are responsive.
http://codepen.io/nirajtech/pen/rmagaL

Answer (score 0):

hard to say without seeing your css (in the question) but presumably you can set the image to be the background and then use this css

```
#image_container{
    /* change image to your image */
    background-image: url('http://mysite.xyz/img/myimage.png');
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using any custom css, only the default materialize.css, you can view the site's page source. I added github link with full source code available. Maybe I'm doing something wrong there, I can't figure it out.

Comment: you will get more help if you're able to post code (html/css/javascript) in your question as most people will not follow external links